# NSArrayController selectedObjects array empty after just setting it

Tags: macos, appkit, nsarraycontroller

I've subclassed NSArrayController, and in one of my setter methods I have this line:

```
BOOL didChangeSelection = [self setSelectedObjects:@[selectedObject]];
```

The `didChangeSelection` variable is set to YES, but if I log `self.selectedObjects` right after this line, it returns an empty array. How can that happen?

Comment: Curious why you subclassed `NSArrayController`. I think that is not very common.

Comment: This is an existing project that I've just started working on, but I believe the goal is just to provide some convenience methods for setting the selected object based on the model that is used in the app.